# Add styling for Can you help? notice

Tags: feature-request, design

In every unanswered question, above the **Your Answer** section we can see the **Can you help?** notice, like:

> Can you help? Stack Overflow depends on everyone sharing their knowledge. If you're able to answer this question, please do!

Currently it is a plain text, instead of that can we add some box styling to that to looks little attractive.

**Current UI:**

> [image: Can you help - Current UI]

**Requesting UI:**

> [image: Can you help - Future request UI]

Currently in the [Travel SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) they applied the box styling for that text.

Comment: I don't see this text at all, either on Stack Overflow or on sites where I have less reputation. Instead, it says: *"Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook."* And I don't know why we'd need to emphasize that text any more than it already is.

Comment: @CodyGray "I don't see this text at all" Probably because you have so much reputation. I only have 1215 rep and I see this text on every question that has no answers.

Comment: I considered that, @dor, but I also checked sites where I have basically no reputation (~100), and I still don't see it. I suppose that means the message is based on your *total network reputation*, rather than your reputation on a particular site.

Comment: @Cody, we're roughly in the same league rep-wise, and I can see the message -- the key is to choose a question with zero answers.

Comment: @frederic [I swear I'm not blind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veSro.png)

Comment: @Cody, indeed you're not. [This](http://imgur.com/a/O84RY) is what I see. Maybe the system doesn't think you can help. What a shame.

Comment: ... how mysterious. I get the "can you help?" request. But I've definitely seen the "know someone who can answer?" request too. I'm not too sure if it would become more visible with a background color however, like it is now in large bold text it already jumps at me. Even more so when there is already another box visible, say on a bountied question.

Comment: @CodyGray: Those notices are [A/B tested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289738)

Comment: Thanks for posting that question, and for sending me the link, @Arulkumar!